# What is "I have my good days" supposed to mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I was reading a novel and encountered this sentence "I have my good days."

And I guess I can't interpret it literally, can I? Because it doesn't make sense.

> A : It is sweet, though.
>   B : I have my good days.

The conversation was kind of like this. I feel like it is some sort of idiom. I can't figure it out.

I don't think the novel's and author's name will help... it is not a published book anyway.

The situation is like this :

Bob proposed to Carol. Bob asked family and friend for permission before popping the question.  Carol accepted and told her family and friends that they are going to marry. But they already knew. Now Carol comes back, and asks Bob "You did it for approval?" And he replies "Yes", so she says "It is sweet, though." Then Bob says "I have my good days."

Thank you again.

Comment: Please name the novel and the author and quote a longer passage for context.

Comment: Is it okay to write it down here?

Comment: May be I should use edit mode

Comment: Compare [*It has its moments.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22it+has+its+moments%22) The expression "damn with faint praise" comes to mind.

Comment: As you can read, I already said that I feel like this sentence has some diffrent meaning. Not literally. I do know what "have" means, sure. Is there any problem for my asking? Shouldn't have I asked a question here? Feeling bit frustrated, sorry. I do not understand your intention since my English is not that good...

Comment: <Compare It has its moments. The expression "damn with faint praise" comes to mind. – FumbleFingers 6> thank you for answer!  I should look it up and work on it. And I think Im getting it. So it is like "that was great experiences asking your mother and friend's approval to inform we will going to gett married, ha ha." In a sarcastic way? Thank you, I gotta look at the praise you told me, really.

Comment: <The particular instances in which one is better or can be seen to have more value, especially when that is not always the case. > i found it, and now I think I can seize it... "see? I do good somtimes." Is that supposed to mean I guess?

Comment: Thank you all for answering and my last quastion is, which one is closed to its meaning? 1. "see? I do good somtimes."  / 2. "that was great experiences asking your mother and friend's approval to inform we will going to gett married, ha ha." In a sarcastic way(peachy)

Answer (score 2):

In this instance it is a modest way to acknowledge and accept a compliment.

Comment: Thank you for answer first of all. So it probably means "thank you, I am sure It was nice of me."? So hard to figure it out since another answer down here is bit diffrent... Thank you so much, though.

Answer (score 0):

When the girl praises the boy for asking permission, the boy is trying to say "I"m not always so dutiful. This instance is actually a bit of an exception to my normal behavior".  It was a "good day", presumably on a "normal" day, he would have behaved differently.

Comment: I feel like you might right. So in other words, this is "I didn't need to be like this much faithful before. I miss good old days the days I wasn't so smitten. I am not like this as you know and this is the only exception, I hope," kind of thing? Conclusively it implys <I haven't been a very good man, so I thought I should have for this one time.>? I like the way you think, wrong or not. So lovely!

Comment: This is a common expression in the UK. It's meant to be frivolous, usually said with a smile.  It really is just a self-effacing, modest way to acknowledge a compliment.  It means, it was no trouble, you're welcome.